# Azure logical app get first date of month

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, workflow-definition-language

I have an Azure Logical app, I want to get the first date of the month two days ago.

```
For example: 
1. If today is '2022-08-01' then two days ago was '2022-07-29', I want to get '2022-07-01' as result
2. If today is '2022-08-02' then two days ago was '2022-07-31', I want to get '2022-07-01' as result
3. If today is '2022-08-03' then two days ago was '2022-08-01', I want to get '2022-08-01' as result
```

I already know I can get date for two days ago using "@addDays(utcNow(), -2, 'yyyy-MM-dd')" but I basically need first date of the month this date belongs to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startOfMonth()` function after calculating for 2 days ago date in order to achieve your requirement. Below is my Logic App flow.

[image]

**RESULTS:**

[image]

You can use the below code-view to reproduce the same in your environment.

```
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "Compose": {
                "inputs": "@startOfMonth(outputs('Compose_2'),'yyyy-MM-dd')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Compose_2": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Compose_2": {
                "inputs": "@addDays(variables('Date'), -2, 'yyyy-MM-dd')",
                "runAfter": {
                    "Initialize_variable": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "Compose"
            },
            "Initialize_variable": {
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "Date",
                            "type": "string",
                            "value": "2022-08-03"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "manual": {
                "inputs": {},
                "kind": "Http",
                "type": "Request"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```